# Menu item with no page, but with dropdown

Tags: menus, dropdown

I am using 2010 theme menu. Is it possible to have a menu item that has a drop down when hovered, but will not click though to a page/post. Just a dropdown, using the wp_nav_menu.

Comment: could you please also give screen shot example. in my case also when i click on page to see dropdown it opens page and no drop down shows. I need to click on at very last where arrow of drop is shown. but my concern is that i should touch on page button anywhere and it should drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a custom menu item from the Appearance>Menu's section of the admin area. When you create the custom menu item just add a # for the link URL. You can name it whatever you want. Then just place the desired pages under that menu item.